# Batch Script - Does the below script gives correct output

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, scripting

Am trying to write IF-ELSE condition in batch script with functions. it not working.
Can you help me if I am anywhere wrong here.
Its working for IF condition goes well. But ELSE not working it was showing below error:
'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
set A=2
if %A%==1 GOTO:GOOD
else GOTO:BAD

:GOOD 
echo All is well
EXIT /B 1

:BAD
echo Wrong
EXIT /B 1
```

Comment: run `if /?` to see the correct syntax for `else`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set A=2
if %A%==1 ( 
    GOTO:GOOD
) else (
    GOTO:BAD
)

:GOOD 
echo All is well
EXIT /B 1

:BAD
echo Wrong
EXIT /B 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to `exit /B 0` if all is good? BTW ATM we share the very same score.